# Optimize DAX query to calcualte initial sales order status and final sales order status

Tags: powerbi, dax, query-optimization, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

Greetings,

I have a requirement where i need to calculate the

sales order status from the point of a product was ordered.

the data which i have for one of the sales order id is as below for a customer.

[image]

Sample Data:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("pdK9DkBAEATgV5GrXTJ36+doUahoVKJiC4kgV3h+p1aQ7GaameTrdhyVAUJ6PEe5ilXqXEKZboYqFOM0SFtYioASCFN38h51fmGvpvjTFzJvIfRG6O3L17ytF3te/nCS8UTGUxnPZDyX8ffntft1rPOjpxs=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Sales Order ID (H)" = _t, #"Product ID (L)" = _t, SnapDate = _t, #"Sales Order Status Name (H)" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Sales Order ID (H)", type text}, {"Product ID (L)", type text}, {"SnapDate", type text}, {"Sales Order Status Name (H)", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Here I am trying to calculate the initial sales order status and final sales order status in a measure based on the dates filters.

For this particular sales order id, the dates are from 18-03-2023 to 28-03-2023 and the initial status is Open Order so the measure should return Open Order and Invoiced as final status in all rows.

Expected Output:
[image]

If the date range selected from 21-03-2023 to 24-03-2023 then the measures should return as below

[image]

Below is the dax which is working fine for me.

```
Sales order status Initial = 
VAR _SalesOrderID = MAX('Sales Orders Snapshots'[Sales Order ID (H)])
VAR _ProductID = MAX('Sales Orders Snapshots'[Product ID (L)])
var _max = MINX(filter(ALLSELECTED('Sales Orders Snapshots'), 'Sales Orders Snapshots'[Sales Order ID (H)] = _SalesOrderID && 'Sales Orders Snapshots'[Product ID (L)] = _ProductID), 'Sales Orders Snapshots'[SnapDate]) 
return 
CALCULATE(MAX('Sales Orders Snapshots'[Sales Order Status Name]), filter(ALLSELECTED('Sales Orders Snapshots') ,  'Sales Orders Snapshots'[SnapDate] =_max && 'Sales Orders Snapshots'[Sales Order ID (H)] = _SalesOrderID && 'Sales Orders Snapshots'[Product ID (L)] = _ProductID))
```

But the issue with performance of this query.

When I do select individual sales order id or customer name from slicer, the query is running fine and showing the results.

But if I don't select anything from any of the slicer, it keeps spinning and after waiting for almost 15 to 20min it gives an error as **Recourses exceeded try filtering to decrease the amount of data displayed.**

The data size of this table is around 9,64,000 records.

Please help me to optimize the above dax.

Thanks in Advance.
Mohan V.